# svn organization with shared classes

Tags: java, svn, repository, repo

Wanted to get some advice regarding best practices for organizing java repos under version control.  I am was planning on having each project under its own repo along with a shared class repo (contains classes that may be used or extended by multiple projects).  Obvious issue would be if anything in the shared class repo gets updated, any bugs would propagate to the other projects.  Any recommendations?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If classes are used by different projects, they usually bundled into a jar and declared as dependency for the other projects (e.g. in the .classpath in eclipse, or by using Ant/Maven/Gradle). Then the other projects can use the classes and also inherit from them.

In a source code repository, you would have separate projects for each jar you produce and no "shared area".

Comment: I'm using Netbeans but I believe I'm doing the equivalent- I add the shared classes jar as a dependency in the project libraries.  Is this a typical organizational structure? Any update to the shared classes project may introduce unwanted errors in any project that has it as a dependency- any recommendations on how to mitigate this?

Comment: Usually, you assign version numbers to your jars, so that a reference to 1.2.0 is stable, because only the newer versions change. For larger projects it is useful to put the jars in a repository (like Nexus or Artifactory) and manage dependencies with Maven or Gradle. Then it is easier to have a development version (-SNAPSHOT) and stable versions.